# I need to print numbers in a range (from , to) at every 1 second gap. I need to implement this in both ways setTimeout & setInterval

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, event-loop

I've a doubt in one output question.

Expectation -> I need to print numbers in a range (from , to) at every 1 second gap. I need to implement this in both ways setTimeout & setInterval. ([Question link](https://javascript.info/task/output-numbers-100ms))

I've made 3 methods -

1. printNumbers(from ,to) -> Using setTimeout or setInterval, it is not working fine (My doubt is in this method, Why it is not taking gap of 1 second)
2. printNumbersT(from ,to) -> Using setTimeout, it is working fine
3. printNumbersI(from ,to) -> Using setInterval, it is working fine

printNumbers(from ,to) is printing all numbers at same time without a gap of 1 second. I want to know how is this working, why it is not taking a gap of 1 second. I need explanation for this.

```
// ❌ not working fine (My doubt is in this method, Why it is not taking gap of 1 second)
const printNumbers = (from, to) => {
    for (let i = from; i < to; i++) {
        setInterval(() => console.log(i), 1000);
    }
}; //

// ✅ working fine
const printNumbersT = (from, to) => {
    let current = from;
    const fun = () => {
        console.log(current);
        if (current < to) {
            current++;
            setTimeout(fun, 1000);
        }
    };
    setTimeout(fun, 1000);
};

// ✅ working fine
const printNumbersI = (from, to) => {
    let current = from;
    const fun = () => {
        console.log(current);
        if (current < to) {
            current++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(timerId);
        }
    };
    const timerId = setInterval(fun, 1000);
};
```

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1awd.png)

Comment: try using a `promise`. it shall execute, wait a sec and execute.

Comment: You don't need `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`, the use of just one of them is sufficient. They are opposite methods that can derive the same functionality. That's like saying you need all of the colors of a crayon box to make the color black.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval and setTimeout are asynchronous, as said in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

> setTimeout() is an asynchronous function, meaning that the timer function will not pause execution of other functions in the functions stack. In other words, you cannot use setTimeout() to create a "pause" before the next function in the function stack fires.

In your for loop you are adding synchronously n function calls to the end of the stack, so they will be fired aproximately at the same time.
To fix this you could use a promise and await its return, or you can change the delay.

```js
const printNumbers = (from, to) => {
    for (let i = from; i < to; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000 * i);
    }
};
```